# chapter 2 rails tutorial - get BUS error after using rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, abort, bus

HI I don't understand the error message I keep getting when I try to use

```
$rake db:migrate
```

in chapter 2 http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app of this rails tutorial.

I'm using 
rvm (latest)
ruby-1.9.2
rails 3.0.6

(I've tried using ruby-1.9.2-p180 and ruby-1.9-2-head in case the error is caused by a bug in one of these version - but I get the same result below.)

The steps are:

```
$ rails new first_app
$ mate Gemfile
```

edit Gemfile to use:
gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'

```
$ bundle install
$ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

works great, then...

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

error:

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
(in /Users/dawnbuie/Documents/Projects/rubyonrails/rails_projects/first_app_again)
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.2p188 (2011-03-28 revision 31204) [i386-darwin10.6.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0029 p:-8251844 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 TOP   
c:0028 p:---- s:0085 b:0085 l:000084 d:000084 CFUNC  :require
c:0027 p:0029 s:0081 b:0081 l:000077 d:000080 BLOCK  /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:6
c:0026 p:0035 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 TOP    /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:2
c:0025 p:---- s:0076 b:0076 l:000075 d:000075 FINISH
c:0024 p:---- s:0074 b:0074 l:000073 d:000073 CFUNC  :require
c:0023 p:0026 s:0070 b:0070 l:000051 d:000069 BLOCK  /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0022 p:---- s:0067 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 CFUNC  :each
c:0020 p:0091 s:0062 b:0062 l:000051 d:000061 BLOCK  /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0019 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 CFUNC  :each
c:0017 p:0046 s:0052 b:0052 l:000051 d:000051 METHOD /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0016 p:0021 s:0048 b:0048 l:000047 d:000047 METHOD /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler.rb:120
c:0015 p:0079 s:0044 b:0044 l:000043 d:000043 TOP    /Users/dawnbuie/Documents/Projects/rubyonrails/rails_projects/first_app_again/config/application.rb:7
c:0014 p:---- s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 FINISH
c:0013 p:---- s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 CFUNC  :require
c:0012 p:0013 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29
c:0011 p:0026 s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 TOP    /Users/dawnbuie/Documents/Projects/rubyonrails/rails_projects/first_app_again/Rakefile:4
c:0010 p:---- s:0029 b:0029 l:000028 d:000028 FINISH
c:0009 p:---- s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 CFUNC  :load
c:0008 p:0334 s:0023 b:0023 l:000022 d:000022 METHOD /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373
c:0007 p:0009 s:0018 b:0018 l:000011 d:000017 BLOCK  /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007
c:0006 p:0009 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 METHOD /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058
c:0005 p:0011 s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 METHOD /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006
c:0004 p:0021 s:0009 b:0009 l:000008 d:000008 METHOD /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991
c:0003 p:0139 s:0006 b:0006 l:000b74 d:000ed4 EVAL   /Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake:35
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000b74 d:000b74 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin/rake:35:in `<main>'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/Users/dawnbuie/Documents/Projects/rubyonrails/rails_projects/first_app_again/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/Users/dawnbuie/Documents/Projects/rubyonrails/rails_projects/first_app_again/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/bundler-1.0.11/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/dawnbuie/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@1.9.2-head-gemset/gems/sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00195cb6 rb_vm_bugreport + 230
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0003f0bf report_bug + 415
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0003f16b rb_bug + 43
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0010df5b sigbus + 27
4   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x97b8246b _sigtramp + 43
5   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
6   libruby.1.dylib                     0x00754f27 rb_intern + 62
7   libruby.1.dylib                     0x0070b7b2 rb_define_module + 32
8   sqlite3_native.bundle               0x004f160f Init_sqlite3_native + 27
9   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00004b84 dln_load + 244
10  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x001791db rb_vm_call_cfunc + 187
11  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0004637e rb_require_safe + 1022
12  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00191020 vm_call_method + 944
13  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0017a855 vm_exec_core + 5397
14  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184afd vm_exec + 1821
15  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184fe6 rb_iseq_eval + 358
16  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00044fb5 rb_load_internal + 293
17  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000463b2 rb_require_safe + 1074
18  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00191020 vm_call_method + 944
19  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0017a855 vm_exec_core + 5397
20  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184afd vm_exec + 1821
21  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0019232c rb_yield + 604
22  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000ac1e rb_ary_each + 62
23  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00191020 vm_call_method + 944
24  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0017a855 vm_exec_core + 5397
25  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184afd vm_exec + 1821
26  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0019232c rb_yield + 604
27  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000ac1e rb_ary_each + 62
28  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00191020 vm_call_method + 944
29  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0017a855 vm_exec_core + 5397
30  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184afd vm_exec + 1821
31  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184fe6 rb_iseq_eval + 358
32  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00044fb5 rb_load_internal + 293
33  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000463b2 rb_require_safe + 1074
34  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00191020 vm_call_method + 944
35  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0017a855 vm_exec_core + 5397
36  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184afd vm_exec + 1821
37  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184fe6 rb_iseq_eval + 358
38  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00044fb5 rb_load_internal + 293
39  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00046998 rb_f_load + 136
40  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00175845 call_cfunc + 581
41  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00191020 vm_call_method + 944
42  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0017a855 vm_exec_core + 5397
43  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184afd vm_exec + 1821
44  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00184e57 rb_iseq_eval_main + 535
45  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000425e9 ruby_exec_internal + 153
46  libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00044b4a ruby_run_node + 90
47  ruby                                0x00001f1f main + 95
48  ruby                                0x00001eb5 start + 53

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Abort trap
```

Could the problem be with the sqlite3 version? 
Ruby?
I looked at the bugreports http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html but nothing matches.

thanks for any insight

Answer (score 2):

I just debugged the same issue on Ubuntu. It may have a similar fix on windows.

The issue was that I had a 1.8 gems folder in my PATH, and it was before the rvm bin, which messes up the sqlite native compile.

So first check your PATH to make sure there are no 1.8 dirs before the rvm ones.
Then follow Michael's steps to uninstall and reinstall the gem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have to recompile SQLite or the sqlite3-ruby gem (or both). Try running

```
$ gem uninstall sqlite3 sqlite3-ruby
$ gem install sqlite3
$ bundle install
```

(The sqlite3-ruby gem will automatically be reinstalled by the bundle command.)